# React route relative file path

Tags: reactjs, relative-path

I'm importing an image source in a component and it's working fine on my local machine. But when I upload the site to my server the images cannot be found anymore and it shows a broken path. On the route `about` my local machine the path is `http://localhost:3000/static/media/myImage.svg` on the remote server it is `http://remoteserver.com/about/static/media/myImage.svg`. Here's the code:

```
import myImage from '../assets/myImage.svg';
...
<img src={myImage} />
```

Comment: Are you *sure* this is the file/import you've an issue with? Importing the image is a build time step, so when the page/image/asset is accessed on a built artifact there's nothing to "fetch", it's already "baked-in" so to say. This is different than specifying a URL path for the image source that is accessed and fetched during run time.

Comment: The issue is appearing when I navigate away from the homepage. The img src remains everywhere relative `src="./static/media/myImage.svg` which then translates to `http://remoteserver.com/about/static/media/myImage.svg`

Comment: Like I said, `import myImage from '../assets/myImage.svg';` is build-time code, not run-time code, so the image is already associated. Nothing should change with regard to this after the app is built and you are deploying out on a server. Do you have some running example of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect? The live site or maybe a `*running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces it? SVG images are a little different in React, have you tried the answer below for importing and rendering it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import {ReactComponent as MyImage}from '../assets/myImage.svg';
...
<MyImage />
```